# Retrofit warning with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I turned proguard on in my android project and got the warning below. Searched on Google but couldn't find much info.

> Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class
>   org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

I've put the retrofit2 proguard rules in my project.

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following proguard rules for Retrofit 2.3.0 and okhttp 3.8.0

```
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
```

Comment: The official rules on the retrofit homepage, plus `-dontwarn javax.annotation.**` were required for me

Answer (score 0):

change it like this:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

Retrofit page has noted about this proguard build,when running on Java 8 VMs:

Why this happens?

Reason is:
Compiler tries to reference Java 8 classes,When u don't mention it through Proguard,After u explicitly mention it,Java 8 classes won't be used.
For example
Package java.nio.* of Java 8 isn't available on Android and will be never called